# Google App Engine Edge Cache not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, caching

I setup the google appengine edge cache before based on the following article.
http://www.xyhd.tv/2011/11/industry-news/setting-cache-control-headers-in-python-to-take-advantage-of-google-appengines-edgecache/

It works perfect until recently. I notice it didn't work anymore 
(all requests status code in logs becomes 200 instead of 204) 
Is there a way to fix it?

## UPDATE (2015/7/20)

The bug has been fixed! NICE!

Comment: Are you using a custom domain?

Comment: After some experiment. I found out a weird thing that the edge cache NOT work with custom domain. Now it only work with *.appspot.com instead..

Comment: I would recommend to open an issue on appengine's public issue tracker

Comment: Great idea, I almost forget the issue tracker. I have submitted the issues now https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12155&thanks=12155&ts=1437073673.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested one of my routes that uses edge cache and it does show 204 status in the logs.  Be sure to include both headers in your response.

```
response.headers['Pragma'] = 'Public'
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=%d'%time
```

It generally takes a few hits back to back before the edge caching starts.

The time value needs to be a minimum of 61 seconds.  I generally set that to at least 120 and it's been working great.

One thing I don't think that article mentions is that the app needs to have billing turned on for this to work.

**Update:**
I uploaded the code you referenced and am getting the 204 response status on the cached url.  In the screenshot below, you will see the first hit was 200 status, then 204s where edge cache kicked in.  The no-cache url returns 200s every time as expected.

[image: Console Logs]

**Update (7/20/2015):**

Edge cache now appears to be working when calling app engine app from either custom domain or APP_ID.appspot.com.  I see 204 response code in the logs now for both. Didn't change any code.

Comment: Still not working here. I tried with the following code.  https://github.com/lucemia/appengine-edge-cache-test . and use the following custom domain to test. http://temp.gliacloud.com/test/cache

Comment: May try removing the Expires header.  That may be causing issues.  If I get a chance, I will try to run that same code sample.

Comment: After some experiment. I found out a weird thing that the edge cache NOT work with custom domain. Now it only work with *.appspot.com instead...

Comment: Yes, my successful test above was with *.appspot.com domain.  I will try again with one of my custom domains when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks, you test results will help me clarify the issues very much. I am pretty sure the custom domain edge cache worked in the past... The custom domain or google reverse proxy behave weird in my point of view.