# CDN caching with App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Can I cache **dynamic** responses from Google App Engine?

[Here's an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431446/google-app-engine-edge-cache-not-working) for Python, but the official docs are pretty light.

I see that I can define [static files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref) to cache, but I'm trying to figure out if I can cache dynamic requests. For example, fetching data that doesn't change very often from Cloud Datastore.

Comment: Perhaps memcache as your first step? Seems to be the approach the Khan Academy took on App Engine: http://bjk5.com/post/2320616424/layer-caching-in-app-engine-with-memcache-and

Comment: BrettJ, thanks for the link. Good read.